# Need help adding cufon code to css in navigation div for Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: css, hover, dreamweaver, cufon

I'm using one of those sample layouts in Dreamweaver CS5, and when I change the font type the hover effect no longer works. Where do I add the cufon coding?

```
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus {
    background: #ADB96E;
    color: #FFF;
}
.container .sidebar1 .nav li a {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use something like Google web fonts, so you can call them using a `<link>` instead of cufon.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDt7r/2/), can you tell me if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: The words should change to white like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raphaelr/SeMhm

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked out for you! ...I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer!